# How to grep a word that has special character '$' in it?

Tags: shell, grep

I have 2 o/p files that I compare to find similar word available. Here is a part of script..

```
Bool=`grep "^$i" File1`
if [ -z "$Bool" ]
then
    echo " $i Not Available"
fi
```

I have a word "profile$" in both the files but I get an output "Not Available" for this.
I tried single quote but then all words that are similar in both files comes as not available.

File 1 output

```
Shared_Docs
tools
tachqe8_rvl
profile$
```

File 2 output

```
tools
tachqe8_rvl
profile$
```

Here my `$i` reads each line from File2 and does a grep to see if it's there in File1. 
If it does not match then echo `$i` not available.

Ideally my echo should be:

```
Shared_Docs
```

But I get

```
Shared_Docs
profile$
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the variable `$i` contain the value `profile$`?  I'm going to assume that it does.

A dollar at the end of the word is tricky.  Without the variable, you could write:

```
 Bool=$(grep '^profile\$' File1)
```

With the variable, we need a trick to suppress the meaning of `$` as a metacharacter:

```
Bool=$(grep "^$i.*" File1)
```

(Note that it is far better to use `$(...)` than the equivalent with back-ticks, aka back-quotes.)

Also, of course, if you want the whole line to be exactly `profile`, then there's no need for special tricks:

```
Bool=$(grep "^$i" File1)
```

should work fine.

---

#### Dealing with the Creature Feep in the Question

```
while read -r i
do
    Bool=$(grep "^$i.*" File1)
    if [ -z "$Bool" ]
    then
        echo " $i Not Available"
    fi
done < File2
```

The `-r` suppresses some expansions that you might otherwise suffer from.  If your shell doesn't like it, drop it; you'll usually be OK without it.

---

#### Another way to do it

If you are looking for missing lines and order is not important, then you could sort both `File1` and `File2` and then use [`comm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html) to compare them, getting the entries that are in `File2` but not in `File1`.  If you've got `bash` and 'process substitution' available, then:

```
comm -13 <(sort File1) <(sort File2)
```

If you don't have process substitution, then:

```
sort -o File1 File1
sort -o File2 File2
comm -13 File1 File2
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because of the "$" at the end "profile$". The "$" is the end-of-line anchor, but it has this special meaning only if it occurs at the end of the RE. Add something harmless at the end of the RE. For example try

grep -i "^$i.*" File1